# In search bar when i am searching key , its still making total no page either there is matches in table or not

Tags: php, html, mysql

When i am searching in search bar , its not making total no page based on search key element here is code

```
<?php               
                 $total_num_page=2;
               if (isset($_GET['page']))
                    {
                        $page_id = $_GET['page'];
                    } 
               else
                    {
                        $page_id = 1;
                    }
                    $search = '' ;
                    if( isset($_POST['search']) )
                    {
                        $search = urldecode($_POST['search']);
                    }
                    else if( isset($_GET['search']) ) 
                    {
                        $search = urldecode($_GET['search']);
                    }
              if ( $search )
              {
                        $all_post_query = "select * from files where recieved_by like '%" . $search . "%' or processed_by like  '%" . $search . "%' or   purpose like  '%" . $search . "%' or file_name like  '%" . $_SESSION["search"] . "%' order by date desc";
                        $all_post_run = mysqli_query($con, $all_post_query);
                        $all_post = mysqli_num_rows($all_post_run);
                        $total_page = ceil($all_post / $total_num_page);
                        $page_start_from = ($page_id - 1) * $total_num_page;
              } 
               else {
                    $all_post_query = "select * from files order by date desc";
                    $all_post_run = mysqli_query($con, $all_post_query);
                    $all_post = mysqli_num_rows($all_post_run);
                    $total_page = ceil($all_post / $total_num_page);
                    $page_start_from = ($page_id - 1) * $total_num_page;
                    }

               ?>
```

and this is place where table is fetching data

```
 <?php
                            if ( $search )
                            {
                                $p_query = "select * from files where recieved_by like '%$search%' or processed_by like  '%$search%' or   purpose like  '%$search%' or file_name like '%$search%' order by date desc limit $page_start_from, $total_num_page";
                            } 
                            else 
                            {

                                $p_query = "select * from files order by date desc limit $page_start_from, $total_num_page";
                            }
                          $p_run=mysqli_query($con,$p_query);
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($p_run)){
                             while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($p_run))
                             {
                                $c_id=$row['id'];
                                $file=$row['file_name'];
                                $purpose=$row['purpose'];
                                $recieve=$row['recieved_by'];
                                $processed=$row['processed_by'];
                                $address=$row['address'];
                                $contact=$row['contact_no'];
                                $date=$row['date'];


                            ?>
```

and this is pagination code

```
<ul class="pagination">
        <?php
        $search_str = '';
        if ($search) {
            $search_str = "&search=" . urlencode($search);
        }
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_page; $i++)
            echo "<li class='" . ($page_id == $i ? 'active' : '') . "'><a href='index.php?page=" . $i . $search_str . "'>$i</a></li>";
        ?>

    </ul>
```

and this is the problem in picture in which when i am searching key in search bar its making total no page and showing total number of pages , which is wrong , some one help me please  [image]

Comment: I suggest you keep keep page no in url as a parameter instead of SESSION .

Comment: please check whether session is unset. using isset(session['key']) function.

Comment: @VimukthiGuruge , please tell me where to use to put the unset so when i am clicking at  any other link so it should leave the search session or when to refresh it

Comment: @tan sir just tell me how to use that and where ?

Comment: @tan , now code is running correct , there was a simple bug in searching code in table, i removed it and working fine , thank you so much sir ,

Comment: You might want to look at the MySQL manual about the use of `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`. But more importantly, read about server side input sanitization. It looks like it matters little in this case, but still you're picking up a dangerous habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Uses search string from POST when posted, uses GET when you click on a page link. If not uses null string.

```
    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
        $page_id = $_GET['page'];
    } else {
        $page_id = 1;
    }
    $search = '' ;
    if( isset($_POST['search']) ) {
        $search = urldecode($_POST['search']);
    }
    else if( isset($_GET['search']) ) {
        $search = urldecode($_GET['search']);
    }
```

Here we uses that keyword in query.

Suggestion : Change query to use COUNT(*) to find the total records instead of using num_rows.

```
    if ( $search ) {

        $all_post_query = "select * from files where recieved_by like '%" . $search . "%' or processed_by like  '%" . $search . "%' or   purpose like  '%" . $search . "%' or file_name like  '%" . $search . "%' order by date desc";
        $all_post_run = mysqli_query($con, $all_post_query);
        $all_post = mysqli_num_rows($all_post_run);
        $total_page = ceil($all_post / $total_num_page);
        $page_start_from = ($page_id - 1) * $total_num_page;
    } else {
        $all_post_query = "select * from files order by date desc";
        $all_post_run = mysqli_query($con, $all_post_query);
        $all_post = mysqli_num_rows($all_post_run);
        $total_page = ceil($all_post / $total_num_page);
        $page_start_from = ($page_id - 1) * $total_num_page;
    }
```

Also here

```
<?php
if ( $search ) {
    $p_query = "select * from files where recieved_by like '%$search%' or processed_by like  '%$search%' or   purpose like  '%$search%' or file_name like '%$search%' order by date desc limit $page_start_from, $total_num_page";
} else {

    $p_query = "select * from files order by date desc limit $page_start_from, $total_num_page";
}
```

Finaly in your pagination append search keyword. With this you loose seach keyword when you click a link other than pagination.

```
<ul class="pagination">
            <?php
            $search_str = '';
            if ($search) {
                $search_str = "&search=" . urlencode($search);
            }
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_page; $i++)
                echo "<li class='" . ($page_id == $i ? 'active' : '') . "'><a href='index.php?page=" . $i . $search_str . "'>$i</a></li>";
            ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: Sir every thing working fine , but it still keep showing total number of page , if there is no still matches

Comment: I cant see any which shows total "number of page" (i can see code for anchors 1,2,3 ... etc), and didn't understood what u mean by "no still matches".

Comment: in search bar when i am searching key , its still making total no page either there is matches in table or not .

Comment: eg: if you have 100 records in table and 10 per page you are seeing 10 pagination link, even your search keyword match only 20 records. in that case you must only see 2 pagination link. is that what you mean ?

Comment: yes , you are right , this is the thing i am asking , sorry for not being clear

Comment: Sorry i accidentally missed one $_SESSION['search'] in your query. please replace that with $search. Edited my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47264224/revisions

Comment: yes this is working fine ,i  find it and its working, thank you so much so so much sir .